# {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."} error displayed

Tags: .net, arrays, c#-4.0, qr-code, barcode-scanner

**Problem**

when I split data in *keydown* event or *textchanged* event for

textbox4 it gives me error.

> {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}

An unhanded exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in

QrReaderSoftware.exe exception

I received data in textbox4 and splitted data to textbox1, textbox2 and textbox3.

**code**

Not work key down:

```
private void textBox4_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  
       {  
           if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)  
           {  
               string[] lines = textBox4.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);  
               textBox1.Text = lines[1].Substring(lines[1].IndexOf(":") + 1);  
               textBox2.Text = lines[2].Substring(lines[2].IndexOf(":") + 1);  
               textBox3.Text = lines[3].Substring(lines[3].IndexOf(":") + 1);  
           }  

       }
```

Line exception error

```
 textBox1.Text = lines[1].Substring(lines[1].IndexOf(":") + 1);
```

but if I use same code above, under button click working success

**why is this problem shown and how to solve the problem ?**

**Updated**

**I added this line to key down event but still error exist**

```
 textBox5.Text = lines[0].Substring(lines[0].IndexOf(":") + 1);
```

**this is text i received by reader in text box 4 and got error**

30 General Conference of Arab Pharmaceutical Unions

UserName : saiad wajeeh

Country : Bahreen

Membership : part

Comment: Array-indexes are zero based

Comment: so that how to do to solve that please

Comment: start with `lines[0]`

Comment: i added line [0] and still error show

Comment: Well, have a look at the lines array from a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

`textBox1.Text = lines[0].Substring(lines[0].IndexOf(":") + 1);

 textBox2.Text = lines[1].Substring(lines[1].IndexOf(":") + 1);

 textBox3.Text = lines[2].Substring(lines[2].IndexOf(":") + 1);`

Comment: can any one help me in that if possible